# Flutter: Management of the state of multiple items in a list view using ChangeNotifierProvider

Tags: listview, flutter, provider, state-management

In my Flutter app,

I want to display multiple items inside a listView,

and I want to handle their state using Provider.

But how can I handle the state in a way that if I edit one item in the listview, then
only that item gets rebuild,

and the entire listview gets rebuild only when I change the number of items either by adding or deleting.

How can I do this?

Comment: Checkout multi provider. It allows you to add a specific provider for each widget

Comment: say that I have over 15 items in the listview, does that mean I need to create a provider object for each item in the listview ?

Comment: why do you care about ListView rebuilding? `ListView.builder` already builds only the necessary children to maintain efficiency

Comment: because the listView.builder is inside a statelessWidget so when the number of items changed (either by adding or deleting) how does the listview.builder know that the number of items has changed so it rebuild to be consistent with the actual items ? @LoVe

Answer (score 3):

This is a working solution that is very close to what you want (It still rebuilds the whole `ListView` when one item is edited but have no worries about efficiency because `ListView.builder` takes care of that for you):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MyModel {
  int modelNumber;

  MyModel(this.modelNumber);

  void edit(int newModelNumber) {
    modelNumber = newModelNumber;
  }
}

class MyModelListWrapper with ChangeNotifier {
  List<MyModel> modelsList;

  MyModelListWrapper(this.modelsList);

  void add(MyModel model) {
    modelsList.add(model);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeAt(int index) {
    modelsList.removeAt(index);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void editModelNumber(int index,int newModelNumber){
    modelsList[index].edit(newModelNumber);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => MyModelListWrapper(
              [...List.generate(15, (index)=>MyModel(index))]),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Consumer<MyModelListWrapper>(
        builder: (_,myModelsListWrapper,__)=> ListView.builder(
          itemCount: myModelsListWrapper.modelsList.length,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ListTile(
            title: Text('${myModelsListWrapper.modelsList[index].modelNumber}'),
            onTap: (){
//              myModelsListWrapper.editModelNumber(index, -1);
              myModelsListWrapper.removeAt(index);
              //or do any other action you want
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```